# Segmentation fault(core dumped) in multi threading in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault, coredump

My code is making me crazy as it sometimes works fine but sometimes get core dumped or segmentation fault or double free(faststop ) error.
I think it's because some threads can not be created but I couldn't make it. What is wrong with this code?
This code is supposed to find \n's in a text file that is stored in path.

Here is the code:

This is Search_inp struct

```
typedef struct Search_inp{
    string * path;
    string * phrase;
    int a ;
    int b;
    int  file_size;
    vector<int>* vec;
}search_inp;
```

This function should return a `void *` pointer to the struct that contains my data that I want to pass to thread!

```
void * make_search_inp(string & path , string & phrase ,  int a , int b , int file_size , vector<int>&vec){
    search_inp * res = (search_inp*)malloc(sizeof(search_inp));
    res->path = &path;
    res->phrase = & phrase;
    res->a = a;
    res->b = b;
    res -> file_size = file_size;
    res->vec = &vec;
    return (void *)res;
}
```

This function will starting the search of \n's in the file

```
// this function will multi thread the search of \n's and do this through search func
void find_backslash(string path , vector<int> &place_backslash , int file_size){
    int counter = 0;
    string backslash = "\n";
    vector<void*>temp;
    vector<pthread_t> tid;
    pthread_t t;
    while(counter * range <= file_size ){
        temp.push_back( make_search_inp(path , backslash , counter*range , (counter+1)*range-1 , file_size , place_backslash ));
        pthread_create(&t, NULL , search , temp.back() );
        tid.push_back(t);
        counter++;
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i<tid.size() ;i++) pthread_join(tid[i] , NULL);
    //when the erorr happend program can not reach this place...
    while(tid.size()) tid.pop_back();
    while(temp.size()) temp.pop_back();
    sort(place_backslash.begin() , place_backslash.end());

}
```

This is search function of my code:

```
void* search(void * temp){
    search_inp* Stemp = (search_inp*)temp;
    string path = *(Stemp->path);
    string phrase = *(Stemp->phrase);
    int a = Stemp->a;
    int b = Stemp->b;
    int file_size = Stemp->file_size;
    vector<int>&vec = *(Stemp->vec); 

    if(path == "" ) return NULL;//check the path correctness

    ifstream fin;//1opening the file 2check if the file opening is successful 3put the g in the correct place with seekg
    fin.open(path.c_str());
    if(a < 0) a=0;
    if(b < 0) b=0;
    if(a >file_size)
        a = b = file_size;
    if(b > file_size){
        b = file_size;
    }
    fin.seekg(a , fin.beg);

    if(!fin){
        cout << "ERROR:File Does Not Exist!" << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    //opening the output file for
    //The search phase
    int counter=0 , charNum =a;//this counter hold the number of appearance of the phrase in the file

    while(!fin.eof() && charNum < b){
        int cnt = 0;char inp;
        do{
        fin.get(inp);charNum++;
        if(phrase[cnt] == inp)
            cnt++;
        else
            break;
        }while( cnt<phrase.length() && !fin.eof());
        if( cnt == phrase.length()){
            counter++;
            vec.push_back( ((int)fin.tellg())-1 );
        }
    }
    fin.close();

}
```

I will run this program calling `find_backslah(path_of_my_file , a vector<int>  , size_of_file)` and get the error sometimes and it isn't happening always.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a minimal but complete example. Also see the posting guidelines for this site.

Comment: You *could* try to catch the crash in action by running your program in a debugger. The debugger will stop at the location of the crash, and let you examine variables and their values, and most importantly let you examine and *walk up* the function call stack, so you can go up to your code (if the debugger didn't stop at your code already). If you still can't figure it out yourself then at least tell us where in your code the crash happens.

Comment: Also, why are you mixing C and C++ so much? If you are programming in C++ you should be using C++ classes and operators. So instead of using e.g. `malloc` to allocate memory you should be using the `new` operator. There are also other problematic things in your code, like using `while (!fin.eof())` which is almost always wrong, and using more pointers than are generally healthy (and problems with pointers is very common when it comes to segmentation faults). You might also want to check out [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks .you are right but is a homework and they asked me to write the code with pointer and pthread.h .

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i marked a point the program cant reach during failure

Comment: Just saying "the program never reaches this point" is not really enough, you really ought to learn how to use a debugger as it's an integral part of programming and locating problems. You should also try to run your program without any threads (instead just call the function in the main thread), with one thread, with two threads, and with many (e.g. 8 maybe?) threads. If it crashes when you're not using threads then you know it's not about the threading itself. Also, if you use any C-style casting you are probably doing something you should not be doing.

Comment: Oh by the way, you have a memory leak, as you never free the memory you allocate with `malloc`. `temp.pop_back();` only removes the pointers from the vector, it doesn't free the memory.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I changed it to {free(temp.back());temp.pop_back();} and i also understand it is something related to threads.steal can not get why.my problem using debuggers is that it happens 10 percent of the time.

Comment: tried to follow the code... raw pointers, pointers to void... no encapsulation... my eyes are bleeding :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just guessing at the problem here, but you pass a (pointer to a) structure to all threads, and all threads have some common pointers that they all share in the structure, for example the `std::vector`. If more than one thread tries to modify the vector at the same time you have a [*race condition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software).

Race conditions are bad and you need to protect against them using some kind of *lock*, for example using [a *mutex*](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes).

Comment: thank you very much. That was absolutely the problem. I was not informed of the concept of locks in that moment. Thank you for your great help.